# how to use replace on a left join statement

Tags: string, postgresql, replace, left-join, trim

I have two tables, one of them has a field with strings like that '1111AAA', the other one has the same field but with this structure '1111 AAA'. I want to replace the blank space with '', but I have an error near the ON of the left join.

I put the code below:

```
select idticket, bt.matricula, bv.vehicle
from b_ticket bt
left JOIN b_vehicle bv ON REPLACE(bv.matricula, ' ', '') ilike ON REPLACE(bt.matricula, ' ', '')
where date_start >= '2019/01/01/'
and date_end <= '2020/01/01'
```

I cannot change the values of any of the two tables. And I also try TRIM function, but it doesn't work because it removes blank spaces of the start and end of the string, not between words.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Error message:
    ERROR:  sintax error near «ON»
    LINE 3: ... bv ON REPLACE(bv.matricula, ' ', '') ilike ON REPLACE...

Comment: Can you post the error (copy-paste) you have when issuing the query

Comment: I add the error message :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have got an extraneous `ON` keyword in your `JOIN` clause:

```
SELECT
    idticket, bt.matricula, bv.vehicle
FROM
    b_ticket AS bt LEFT JOIN b_vehicle AS bv
        ON REPLACE(bv.matricula, ' ', '') ILIKE REPLACE(bt.matricula, ' ', '')
WHERE
    date_start >= '2019/01/01/' AND date_end <= '2020/01/01';
```

As the error states: predicate must be any valid boolean expression, but it cannot have a `ON` keyword in it.

Comment: oh... yes, I duplicate ON, thank you, I was looking around 30 minutes and I don't see that error... thanks!

Comment: @Imrik, Yes it happens. Carefully reading the error must be the first step. Using indentation and typesetting rules also helps a lot because it increases readability and ease maintenance. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid SQL:

```
left JOIN b_vehicle bv 
    ON REPLACE(bv.matricula, ' ', '') ilike ON REPLACE(bt.matricula, ' ', '')
```

There should be only one `ON` per `JOIN`. Presumably, you want:

```
left JOIN b_vehicle bv 
    ON REPLACE(bv.matricula, ' ', '') ilike REPLACE(bt.matricula, ' ', '')
```

Comment: oh... yes, I duplicate ON, thank you, I was looking around 30 minutes and I don't see that error... thanks!